# Как найти заданный элемент в массиве с поиском по индексу без использования метода includes

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно найти заданный элемент в массиве с поиском по индексу без использования метода includes

```
numbers.includes = function (faundElem, arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr; i++) {
    if (this[i] === faundElem) {
      return true;
    }
      введите сюда код
  }
  return false;
};
```

Comment: Ну оформите код так, чтобы его можно было прочитать

Comment: Вам нужно - вы и ищите) вы хотяб чуть-чуть уважаете тех, кто вам будет отвечать? не оформлен код, нет знаков препинания, не описана суть проблемы... пока могу помочь только минусом.

Comment: Вы можете посмотреть как написал полифил к методу includes и написать что-то похожее

Comment: какие у вас входные данные? какие выходные? 
Вам нужно имея элемент узнать его index или что?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я не понял что именно нужно, но вот код без includes

```
let array = [2,4,6,8,9] //Массив
let index = 1 //Индекс
let item = 4 //Нужный элемент
console.log(array[index] == item)
```

Comment: Видимо - да, вы не поняли. Нужен поиск.